# Тормоза при использовании библиотек Adafruit GFX и Adafruit SSD1306

Tags: arduino, display

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой. Делаю штуковину-фиговину на базе arduino pro mini, oled дисплея 128х64, куча датчиков, переменные резисторы для установки пользовательских значений, светодиоды ...и в общем не важно. Проблема в том, что в этой штуковине-фиговине я использую три светодиода для индикации состояния, которые в разных состояниях должны красиво мигать с затуханием вот по этой простой формуле `int(abs(255.00 * sin(value)));`, где value это величина, которая прибавляется в функции `loop`, в которой в конце я вставил `delay(1)`, и когда я попытался еще параллельно выводить анимацию на дисплей, частота срабатывания функции `loop` резко снизилась. Это приводит к тому, что красивое плавное мигание диодов превращается в жуткое мерцающее зрелище. Вот теперь сижу и думаю либо это библиотека такая тяжелая и может быть есть что попроще, либо в любом случае и с любой библиотекой будет такое происходить, либо я сам дурак и можно как-то по другому реализовать не завязываясь на `loop`? Спасибо.

P.S. На Mega 2560 такое же поведение, причем влияет именно вызовы методов очистки и отрисовки экрана.

Comment: Я бы попробовал убрать `sin()`, поскольку это "тяжёлая" функция, и посмотрел бы производительность скетча без неё. А вообще было бы неплохо увидеть код скетча.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить переходом на другую библиотеку - OLED_I2C (http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=79). Что там происходит внутри библиотек не разбирался, но штуковина-фиговина заработала очень хорошо, и экран воспроизводит анимацию, и диоды плавно мигают. При этом код не подвергался оптимизации все осталось как было, изменения затронули только подключение новой библиотеки и вывод данных на экран.